# How to remove all options of select tag and assign a new list of items to select options in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="property" onchange="change()">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
</select>
<select id="value">
     <option>a</option>
     <option>b</option>
     <option>c</option> 
 </select>
```

change() function in javascript should remove existing options in "value" and assign new list of entries like (x,y,z)

Answer (score 1):

This is the **most dynamic script** with no limitations.

The below script will help you if **you have any number of options** in first **`select`** based on which second `select box` would populate.

**CODE :**

```js
 var dynamicArray = {
   1: ["a", "b", "c"],
   2: ["p", "q", "r"],
   3: ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
   4: ["l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"]
 }

 function makeSubmenu(value) {
   if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("dynamicSelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
   else {
     var populateOptions = "";
     for (secondOpt in dynamicArray[value]) {
       populateOptions += "<option>" + dynamicArray[value][secondOpt] + "</option>";
     }
     document.getElementById("dynamicSelect").innerHTML = populateOptions;
   }
 }

 function resetSelection() {
   document.getElementById("mainSelect").selectedIndex = 0;
   document.getElementById("dynamicSelect").selectedIndex = 0;
 }
```

```html
<body onload="resetSelection()">
  <select id="mainSelect" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
    <option disabled>Select Here...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <select id="dynamicSelect" size="1">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</body>
```

What you need to do is just **give same array elements** for respective options.
Here as you can see array named `dynamicArray` holds your `select box 1, 2, 3, 4` width there respective value. This `1, 2, 3, 4` is nothing but your content of first select box that in your HTML like `<option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option>`.

So if you change this(1, 2, 3, 4) in HTML do not forget to change in array too.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mbw921x/)

You can use `innerHTML` to change the values in a select box. Try the below code.

**JS**

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "<option>x</option>
       <option>y</option>
       <option>z</option>";
}
```

If you want the options populated according to the value selected in the first dropdown, please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mbw921x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

if u use `onchange()`, u must write your js code in your html.but don't use javascript code in html file.So better try by jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#property').on("change",function(){    
  var new_option ="<option>x</option><option>y</option><option>z</option>";     
  $('#value').empty().append(new_option);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bga6gsd7/1/) for this problem.

What I did was add this inside `change()`:

```
elem = document.getElementById("value");

//FOR DELETING
length = elem.children.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length ; i++)
    elem.removeChild(elem.children[0]);

//FOR ADDING
var value;
for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    switch(i){
        case 0:
            value = "x";
            break;
        case 1:
            value = "y";
            break;
        case 2:
            value = "z";
            break;
    }        
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    elem.appendChild(option);
}
```